# Express Js is unable to retrieve submitted form data from React Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to submit post data from React Js to Express but there is no data been passed to `body`.

**App.js from React**

```
function submitForm(){
    axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/submit-student',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {name: 'John Doe'}
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Data has been saved.')
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('Internal server error')
    })
}
```

**api.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/submit-student", function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.body)
    console.log(res)
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have set a testing data inside the `body` which will be passed to `api.js` that read the port `9000`. The submission is fine. The only issue is that, the `req.body` is returning an empty json array `{}`. It read `Data has been saved.` message but the `console.log(res)` showing empty array at the body section.

[image]

there is no error appeared when submission. I even tried postman and it can retrieve the post data.

**EDIT**

I have `bodyParser` included in my `server.js` file.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const routes = require("./routes/api");

mongoose.connect("mongodb-url-here", { 
    useNewUrlParser: true 
})

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
    console.log('Mongoose is connected!');
})

app.use('/api', routes);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `body` option to `data` for `axios`. See [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig) about how to send a POST request.

`api.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/submit-student', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const api = require('./api');

const app = express();
const port = 9000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server start'));
```

client-side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  axios({
    url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/submit-student',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { name: 'John Doe' }
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Data has been saved.');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Internal server error');
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server Logs:

```
server start
{ name: 'John Doe' }
```

Comment: You are right! It's because of the `body`. I switched to `data` and it's working now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**

you need the middleware "body parser"

add this into your app.js or server.js file  ( server side )

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

**Solution 2:**
( react side )

```
function submitForm(){
    axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/submit-student',
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({name: 'John Doe'}), // body must be raw ( as a plain string should do it )
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'Application/json'} // need the type of the content that is being send
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Data has been saved.')
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('Internal server error')
    })
}
```

in axios the body that you send to the server should be raw and the call contain the header `{ 'Content-Type': 'Application/json'}`

Comment: I have this parser in my server.js

Comment: try solution 2. i think it need a raw data into the body

Comment: Tried it and unfortunately, it's still the same :(

Comment: what is the response of the axios call? is it a 404? also `console.log(req)`, should be before `res.send(req.body)`

Comment: It returned 200.

Comment: just to humor me, add the header into the axios call

Comment: it looks like in the axios you should  change `body` with `data` https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig